# What is this game with skeletal characters?

Tags: game-identification

I've forgotten the name of the pictured game. Do you know it?

[image: game screenshot]

Comment: You can search by images using Google: http://goo.gl/4M2qzI

Comment: GRIM FANDANGOOO!!! Definitely worth playing. I think there's even a remastered version.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is a classic.  [Grim Fandango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grim_Fandango).

If you missed out on the original release of this game, updated re-release [Grim Fandango Remastered](http://www.grimremastered.com) is available for purchase on a variety of platforms.

Comment: And if you have not played it so far, you are really missing out on an excellent game.

Comment: It did have great music track as well